# Specify plot area in a multiplot

Tags: r, plot

I create a row of plots in a graphic device with the par() command and run the first 2 plots:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 4))
hist(mydata)
boxplot(y ~ x)
```

Now let's say the boxplot is wrong and I want to replace it with a new one. By default the next plot goes to the left side of the previous one (or one row below, first column, in case of a multiple rows layout), leaving the previous plot unchanged.

Is there a way to specify the location of the next plot in the multiplot grid area?

Comment: Yes, there is. Check option `mfg` in `par()`.

Comment: @TheodoreLytras This has been discussed in Greg answer below. Using mfg doesn't clear the previous plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base graphics model is ink-on-paper and does not allow revisions. The lattice and ggplot models are based on lists that can be modified. You can "go back" an add items with `lines`, `points` and as pointed out you can change the focus to a particular panel, but to remove or replace stuff .... not possible. Re-running the code shouldn't be a big problem, should it? Pixels are very cheap.

Comment: I have this problem during exploratory data analysis, rather than programming. Sometimes I want to plot multiple variables against my target and compare them. If I miss one parameter in the plot command, then I have to start all over again from the first plot. Not a big deal but it can get annoying sometimes.

Comment: Need adopt an integrated development environment so you can edit and re-run code: RStudio seems to be the most popular these days, although ESS was the former leader.

Answer (score 3):

To specify the location of the next plot in the multiplot grid area, I prefer to use the function `layout`.
The `layout` function provides an alternative to the `mfrow` and `mfcol` settings.
For example the equivalent of `par(mfrow = c(1, 4))` is :

```
     layout(matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 4), byrow=TRUE, ncol=4))
```

or

```
     layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), byrow=TRUE, ncol=4))
```

The function `layout.show()` may be helpful for visualizing the figure regions
that are created. The following code creates a figure visualizing the layout
created in the previous example:

```
  layout.show(4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the next frame to plot to useing the `mfg` argument to `par`.  See `?par` for details.  So a command like:

```
par(mfg=c(1,2))
```

Will mean that the next high level plot will go to the plot in the 1st row 2nd column.  This can be used to plot in your own custom order.  However, using `layout` for this is probably easier better in most cases.

When you use this to specify a frame to plot in R assumes that the frame is ready to be plotted in, it will not remove anything already there, so if there is an existing plot there it will be plotted over and you will likely see both plots and it won't look pretty.

You can draw a rectangle over the top of an existing plot to give yourself a blank frame to plot in using code like:

```
par(xpd=NA)
rect( grconvertX(0, from='nfc'), grconvertY(0,from='nfc'), 
grconvertX(1,from='nfc'), grconvertY(1, from='nfc'), 
col='white',border='white')
```

This works OK for looking at on the screen, but you need to be careful with this if exporting or printing, in some cases the printer or interpreter of the graphics file will interpret the white rectangle as "do nothing" and you will again see both plots.

In general it is best to do plots that take more than a line or 2 of code in a script window so that if you want to change something you can edit the script and just recreate the whole plot from scratch rather than relying on tricks like this.